# Rendering Output Panel if List is not null

Tags: visualforce, rendered

I want to render an outputpanel if list is not null.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="opformofauth" style="width:100%" rendered="{!lstPersonWrapper != null}">
....
</apex:outputpanel>
```

This is not working as expected

Comment: btw you can also use not(lstPersonWrapper.isempty)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
     <apex:outputPanel id="opformofauth" style="width:100%" rendered="{!lstPersonWrapper.size!=0}">
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Answer (score 9):

I would try to use the function `ISBLANK` to determine if the list is blank or null:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="opformofauth" 
                  style="width:100%" 
                  rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(lstPersonWrapper))}">
    ...
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Additionaly you can check whether the list has any enties:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(lstPersonWrapper))}">
    <apex:outputPanel id="opformofauth" 
                      style="width:100%" 
                      rendered="{!lstPersonWrapper.size != 0}">
        ...
    </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:outputPanel>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Render it like as:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="opformofauth">
    <apex:outputPanel  style="width:100%" rendered="{!lstPersonWrapper != null}">
       ....
    </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to render component if list is not null and not empty

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!objList != null && !objList.empty}">Test</apex:outputPanel>
```